# Print non-string variables in one line separated by space Haskell

Tags: variables, haskell, printing, io, output

I have two int variables and want to print them on one line, separated by space. How to achieve this in Haskell?

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    let one = 1
    let two = 2

    print ( one, two ) -- 1 option
    mapM_ (putStr . show) [one, two]  -- 2 option
    print (one ++ " " ++ two)  -- 3 option
```

1 option give result: (1,2)

2 option give result: 12

3 option give error:

`No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from the literal '2'`

So how do I print two values in one line, separated by space?

Comment: Hi - I know it's confusing, as most other languages use `print` but you should try to avoid that (use `putStrLn` instead) as it will always add a `show` and this is usually not what you want - using `putStrLn` will force you to think about how to format too (as it works only with `String`s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the elements to a `String`, for example with `show`:

```
print (show one ++ " " ++ show two)
```

You can also work with [**`intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate) to add a separator between the strings, so:

```
import Data.List(intercalate)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn ((intercalate " " . map show) [one, two])
```

This makes it easy to extend this to an arbitrary number of elements.

Comment: @vytaute: `intercalate " "` is also called `unwords` in the `Prelude`, e.g.: `putStrLn $ unwords $ map show [one, two]`. If the variables are of different types, you can use `[show one, show two]` instead of `map show […]`. Also, note that its cousin, `unlines`, is not exactly the same as `intercalate "\n"` because `unlines` appends an additional `"\n"`.

Answer (score 3):

also (if you know other languages like C) you might find [`printf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#v:printf) easy to use as well - it'll give you some flexibility - your example could be

```hs
printf "%d %d\n" one two
```

There is a bit of "magic" going on so that you could use this to get back either an `String` or use it inside `IO` to print to the console directly:

```hs
ghci> printf "%d %d\n" 1 2
1 2

ghci> printf "%d %d\n" 1 2 :: String     
"1 2\n"       

ghci> :t it
it :: String
```